# Confusion about the EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am reading through the [EM-Algorithm](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse312/11wi/slides/12em.pdf) but on the slide 39, I don't get how

$$P(D) = P(D|A)P(A) + P(D|B)P(B)$$

I am trying to understand it in order to get my head around modelling with mixture of Gaussians. Can anyone explain me how to get that result?

Comment: That formula is the Law of Total Probability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), it applies in many cases besides EM algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since my probability lectures but I got it !

Comment: @user27840 Even though single-sentence answers are normally frowned upon, I think your response is quite possibly as complete an answer as is likely to be needed for such a question (since it arises from the OP forgetting a basic probability result). If you see a way of expanding your comment even a little (perhaps by inserting the intermediate step of $=P(DA)+P(DB)$, or by including a Venn diagram, or both, say) would you maybe consider posting an answer? Note that your comment has 6 upvotes already.  I'm happy to insert a diagram for you (that fits with whatever you post) if that helps.